# Ortho projection of 3D points with a vector

Tags: geometry

I have 3D points and I need to make an 2D orthographic projection of them onto a plane that is defined by the origin and a normal `n`. The meaning of this is basically *looking at the points from the top (given the vertical vector)*. How can I do it?

What I'm thinking is:

1. project point P onto the 3D plane: `P - P dot n * n`
2. look at the 3D plane from the "back" in respect to the normal (not sure how to define this)
3. do an ortho projection using max-min coordinates of the points in the plane to define the clipping

Answer (score 0):

First, $\hat{n}\times(\mathbf{v}\times\hat{n})$ gives your projection.  It's the same as what you have already.

Then do an active 3D rotation such that $\hat{n}$ is rotated to $\hat{z}$.

Finally, rotate around $\hat{z}$ to get the 2D orientation that you want.

Once you have that, do whatever clipping you need based on the new coordinates that you have.